# DataFrameGroupBy object to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to group the values in a `pandas.DataFrame` that I have and then store the results I want to keep in an another dataframe.

I have the following code:

```
grouped = df.groupby("date")
grouped_df = DataFrame()
grouped_df["work_count"] = grouped["id"].count()
grouped_df["author_author"] = grouped["author_name"].nunique()
print(grouped_df)
```

With it, I get:

```
            commit_count  authors_count
date                                   
2018-02-16             1              1
2018-02-23             2              1
2018-03-02             5              1
2018-03-30             1              1
2018-04-13             3              1
2018-06-15             2              1
```

I have tried to use `indices` to get the dates, like so:

```
grouped = df.groupby("date")
grouped_df = DataFrame()
grouped_df["date"] = grouped.indices
grouped_df["work_count"] = grouped["id"].count()
grouped_df["author_author"] = grouped["author_name"].nunique()
print(grouped_df)
```

And with it, I get stuck with this:

```
                 date    work_count   author_count
2018-02-16 2018-02-16             1              1
2018-02-23 2018-02-23             2              1
2018-03-02 2018-03-02             5              1
2018-03-30 2018-03-30             1              1
2018-04-13 2018-04-13             3              1
2018-06-15 2018-06-15             2              1
```

I have also tried :

```
grouped = df.groupby("date", as_index=False)
```

But I get:

```
ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series
```

Besides I want to keep the dates as a column in the dataframe and I wouldn't be able to achieve that with `as_index=False`.

Finally, I would like to remove that first column from `grouped_df`.
I want my result to look like the following:

```
      date    work_count   author_count
2018-02-16             1              1
2018-02-23             2              1
2018-03-02             5              1
2018-03-30             1              1
2018-04-13             3              1
2018-06-15             2              1
```

Comment: What's the difference between your end result and your starting point? They look identical

Comment: @BrianJoseph with my starting point date isn't a column (Notice "date" is one row below the other column names), the are indices and not values. If I try using grouped_df["date"], I get a key error. In my end result, "date" is a column and the dates are values in that column.

Answer (score -1):

grouped = df.groupby("date", as_index=False).reset_index()

Comment: Using this, I would lose "date" and I want to keep it.